# C - printing row and column

Tags: c, c89

Please explain to me how to make the program do the reseting of `col` every time it went thru the loop to increase `col`.

i would like to print an X amount of `rows` and `cols` controlled by the `LENGTH`.

the code is obviously a huge mess, and i had to kind of unroll the loop. my question is how to loop correctly there actually???

it seemed very simple actually but i really couldn't wrap my head around it.
for the moment, all i want to do is get the output to something like the following;

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 0, col: 0| row: 0, col: 1| row: 0, col: 2| row: 0, col: 3|
|----------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 1, col: 0| row: 1, col: 1| row: 1, col: 2| row: 1, col: 3|
|----------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 2, col: 0| row: 2, col: 1| row: 2, col: 2| row: 2, col: 3|
|----------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 3, col: 0| row: 3, col: 1| row: 3, col: 2| row: 3, col: 3|
|----------------------------------------------------------------
```

it prints it out "all fine" (more or less) so far, but it's so stupid how i wrote that, obviously...
yeah, sorry for coding like a recluse,
and thanks everybody for taking your time!
i'm absolutely sure you know how to do a lot better, and can perhaps explain what i'm missing here.

cheers!

```
float LENGTH    = 0.0f;
int row = 0;
int col =0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    LENGTH = 8.0f;
    
    
    row = 0;
    col =0;
    
    for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
    {
        for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
        {
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 1;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 2;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 3;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 4;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < GRID_LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 5;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 6;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 7;
            col = 0;
            for (;row < LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            row = 8;
            col = 0;
            for (;row <= LENGTH; row++)
            {
                for (;col <= LENGTH; col++)
                {
                    printf("| r:%4i , c:%4i ", row, col);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

the c89 tag is there, because the program needs to run in that configuration.

the reason for that is, my plan is to dynamically allocate
a number of vectors. and for that i don't want to use variable-length-arrays.

let's imagine we want to create a grid like a checker board or chess board or something of that nature. the grid should be centered in the world (x=0, y=0, z=0).
so, if the grid would be only of `LENGTH = 1` then we still need 4 vectors to draw 4 lines, to get a quad at least...
but, if the user of the function calls it with

`LENGTH = 1` ,

then we need to add 1 to each length
`(length +1)` so that when the user calls it with `LENGTH = 1`
we get actually at least 2x2 vectors out of it.

in the code below i'm not sure if `vector` should be named `vector_array` for example, since i allocate all the vectors i want.

```
size_t count = (((length +1) * (length +1)));
float *vector;
vector = NULL;
vector = calloc(count, sizeof(float) * 3);
```

my question there is, how to allocate the array of vectors, with the positions we get out of the loop so that `row` and `col` are both initialized like following `row = -length` and `col = -length`

please ignore, and forgive me, that i used `LENGTH` and `length` interchangeably.. they mean the same all in all but `LENGTH` should be used to initialize it to 1 perhaps...

```
    size_t LENGTH = 0;
    
    
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        LENGTH = 8;
        
        float *vector;
        vector = NULL;
        vector = calloc(3, sizeof(vector));
        if (vector == NULL)
        {
            printf("allocation of vector failed!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        
        float **vector_array;
        vector_array = NULL;
        vector_array = calloc( ((LENGTH+1) * (LENGTH+1)), sizeof(vector));
        if (vector_array == NULL)
        {
            printf("allocation of vector array failed!\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        row = (int)-LENGTH;
        col = (int)-LENGTH;
        
        while (row < (int)LENGTH)
        {
            while (col < (int)LENGTH)
            {
                vector_array[row] = row;
                vector_array[col] = col;
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
        
        row = (int)-LENGTH;
        col = (int)-LENGTH;
        while (row <= (int)LENGTH)
        {
            
            while (col <= (int)LENGTH)
            {
                printf("c:%d\n", vector_array[col]);
                col++;
            }
            printf("r:%d\n", vector_array[row]);
            row++;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

i can't explain it better what i try to do.
i'm a beginner and i do C as a hobby...

thank you very much!

Comment: If the code is working and you want feedback or improvement suggestions then it would be more appropriate to post the question over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have a specific problem (e.g incorrect output) then please update the question to provide details of the exact problem.

Comment: how do i make the program do the reseting for me every time it went thru the loop. i would like to print an X amount of rows and cols controlled by the LENGTH. the code is obviously a huge mess. and i had to kind of unroll the loop. my question is how to loop correctly there actually???

Comment: unrolling the loop that never existed, that is...

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66081783/edit) the question with any updated info.

Comment: Why did you tag the question as C89? Is this intentional? Are you using a 30 year old version of the language?

Comment: yes i'm using C89. 
variable sized arrays came with C99, that i know but i won't use C99 i need to make it C89 compatible.

Comment: @Nickname: If you don't want variable-length arrays (VLAs), you can just state so, as in C11, they have been downgraded to an optional feature, which the compilers are not required to implement. They were only required in C99. However, if there are other reasons why your code must be C89-compliant, then it is appropriate to keep this tag.

Comment: don't worry about the tag please :) 
my question is; how to improve on that code so it doesn't have to be unrolled in loop in a loop.. sort of in a way.. hard to say what my question is sometimes, because that would mean that i know where the problem myself.. then i should be able to solve it too on my own... maybe you understand

Comment: @Nickname: If the tag is not important, then please delete it. Otherwise, I will have to post a C89-compliant answer.

Comment: no, it is important. i tell u why i think it is important. i'll edit the thing... on moment please

Comment: I have now provided a C11-compliant solution to the problem. Do you want me to make it C89-compliant by moving the loop counter declarations outside of the `if` statement? Or did you just not want me to use VLAs?

Comment: *the code is obviously a huge mess* yes indeed, but can you state your goal in a small paragraph (5 lines max).

Comment: okay lemme try.. 1. have a fully dynamic vector array with 3 float vector positions, 2. initialize it with a float LENGTH of any possible size, 3. have a row col loop (that will be expanded to work in 3 dimensions, so row becomes X, Y, and col becomes Z) 4. have the data from the loop first data point will be -4,  0, -4 for a length of 8, since the row and col start from 
-length /2 4. change the data thru the loop, and print it out as list or like what i tried as a nice block, better would be a grid but its more or less similar to the block print method

Comment: Note that you can write `float vector[3] = {0};` instead of using `float *vector; vector = calloc(count, sizeof(float) * 3);`? It should be no problem to use the stack for such small arrays of fixed size. However, if you later want to make the array significantly larger, maybe it is a good idea to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: i know it's 2:23 in the morning but maybe you like to explain on how you would go about to initialize the array of vectors, with vectors, with the position that were created with the loop you made... :)

Comment: @Nickname: What exactly do you mean with `"the grid should be centered in the world (x=0, y=0, z=0)"`? A chess board would normally have the indices `0` to `7` for both dimensions. Do you want it to have the values `-4` to `+3` instead? Or do you want the game world to be more complex than a chess or checkers game board, where the player can move freely (possibly with unlimited exploration in an infinite map)?

Comment: yes, it's not about a chess board indeed.. i would like to generate data for opengl to draw some lines, so its a little more complicated because i will always need to draw one line more than the LENGTH, to get a 4x4 grid i would need to draw 5 lines in each direction X and Z, you hopefully have 5 fingers (on each hand) if you spread those 5 fingers there should be 4 gaps in between. so the locations i actually need range from -4 to and including +4 if we set the LENGTH to 8, if i'm correctly.

Comment: and since it should work in 3d it's probably not very favourable to print it out as a block, and much better as a list even tho they are a bit harder to read.. my question now is how to initialize the array of vectors that i imagine could look a bit like that in pseudo code `vector_array[row][col][vector]` the vector would be created like `float* vec;`
`vec = NULL;`
`vec = calloc(3, sizeof(float));` and the array would be created like `size_t array_length = ((LENGTH +1) * (LENGTH +1));`
`float** vec_array;`
`vec_array = NULL;`
`vec_array = calloc(array_length, sizeof(vec));` size_t LENGTH

Comment: @Nickname: If your game world consists of [voxels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel), then you will probably have to use a 3D array to represent the game world. For example, if the game world consists of 100*100*100 (=1 million) voxels, then you would create it like this: `struct voxel (*voxels)[100][100] = malloc( 100*100*100*sizeof(struct voxel) );`The `struct voxel` should contain all the data required for a single voxel.

Comment: @Nickname: However, if all you want is to store a list of lines in order to pass it to OpenGL, then this list should be stored in the format that OpenGL expects. I am not very familiar with OpenGL, so I would have to know exactly what OpenGL function you are using, so that I can look it up in the documentation in order to find out what format OpenGL expects.

Comment: hey again! :) opengl expects data from point A ---> point B, a list of 3d vector position data.  for example i drew some orientation lines from 0,0,0 to positive 64 in X, Y and Z.                             `float data[] =
 {
  
         0,   0,   0,    //from
  p,   0,   0,    //to
  
  0,   0,   0,    //from
  0,   p,   0,    //to
  
  0,   0,   0,    //from
  0,   0,   p,    //to
 };`

Comment: and the lines are drawn like that `glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, buffer);
 glEnableVertexAttribArrayARB(attrib->position);
 glVertexAttribPointerARB( attrib->position, components, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
 glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, count);
 glDisableVertexAttribArrayARB(attrib->position);
 glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);`

Comment: sorry man i dont know how text formatting works in comments here... i can' even make a new line, without adding the comment i just wrote

Comment: @Nickname: Yes, it is very hard to post code in comments. You may want to post it on an external site, such as https://pastebin.com/, and sent me a link to your post there.

Comment: @Nickname: What exactly do you mean when you use the word vector? Do you mean vector [in the mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics))? Are you referring to the position of the end of a line relative to the start of the line? Or do you mean [vertex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(computer_graphics))? Or are you referring to a one-dimensional array?

Comment: i guess it can be all the same thing, i just didn't figure out how to set it up...

Comment: @Nickname: I have now updated my answer to answer your second question.

Comment: @Nickname: I have edited my answer to fix a bug. It seems that I had mixed up the horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: it's alright i was messing around with opegl/glfw stuff, so i didn't test it out yet anyways.. but i will.. i have to study those loops

Comment: If you want me to be notified of your comment, you should use `@` and my name. Otherwise, I may not notice your comment. This is not necessary in the comments section to my answer, as I will automatically be notified of all comments to my answer. But we are here in the comments section of your question, so only you will be automatically notified of all comments.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel okay, sorry i didn't knew... for today i'm done! but tomorrow i will try it out. and when i can ask a question then i will post one about shaders and the problems with glsl, datatypes/storage class or what is is... basically there are a bunch of varying, uniform and attribute's in a shader i would like to use but every time i set the windowhints to version 410 it says i doesnt know about that syntax and, kind of vice versa.. just all super strange.. i got it to work in one project, but i want to find out why it sometimes seems to work and why sometimes not, but never did shaders

Comment: @Nickname: Unfortunately, I can't help you much with OpenGL, as I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is nested to four levels. This is unnecessary. You should only need two levels of nesting. Every iteration of the outer loop should deal with one row, and every iteration of the inner loop should deal with a column of the row.

Generally, you should not modify the loop counter outside the `if` statement, as this is likely to make your code messy and hard to understand. There are only rare situations in which this is appropriate (and this is not one of them).

Also, comparing integers with floating point numbers is generally a bad idea, as floating-point numbers have limited precision. Therefore, they will often not be exactly equal, and the comparison will fail. For example, if you compare the integer `7` with `6.99999999998`, then the result of the comparison may be false, although the numbers are practically equal. When comparing floating-point values, you should generally allow for a certain tolerance, for example by determining whether the difference between the two values exceeds a certain threshold.

Here is a C89-compliant solution to the loop problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 4
#define NUM_COLS 4

int main( void )
{
    int row, col;

    for ( row = 0; row < NUM_ROWS; row++ )
    {
        // print first line containing only a static horizontal bar
        printf( "|" );
        for ( col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++ )
            printf( "-----------------" );
        printf( "\n" );

        //print second line containing the variable information
        for ( col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++ )
            printf( "| row: %i, col: %i ", row, col );

        //print vertical bar at end of line
        printf( "|\n" );
    }

    //print static horizontal bar
    printf( "|" );
    for ( col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++ )
        printf( "-----------------" );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing not C89-compliant about the code above are the single-line comments (`//`). You may have to replace them with multi-line comments (`/*` and `*/`) if you want strict C89 compliance. However, most C89 compilers accept single-line comments as a language extension.

The above code contains a bit of code duplication. This code duplication can be removed, by breaking from inside the outer loop, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_ROWS 4
#define NUM_COLS 4

int main( void )
{
    int row, col;

    //NOTE: Leaving out the middle expression of the "for" statement
    //      will make it always true.
    for ( row = 0; ; row++ )
    {
        // print first line containing only a static horizontal bar
        printf( "|" );
        for ( col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++ )
            printf( "-----------------" );
        printf( "\n" );

        //break out of loop, if past last row
        if ( row == NUM_ROWS )
            break;

        //print second line containing the variable information
        for ( col = 0; col < NUM_COLS; col++ )
            printf( "| row: %i, col: %i ", row, col );

        //print vertical bar at end of line
        printf( "|\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code is now shorter (if you disregard the additional comment), but it may be a bit harder to understand.

Both of these programs print the following output:

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 0, col: 0 | row: 0, col: 1 | row: 0, col: 2 | row: 0, col: 3 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 1, col: 0 | row: 1, col: 1 | row: 1, col: 2 | row: 1, col: 3 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 2, col: 0 | row: 2, col: 1 | row: 2, col: 2 | row: 2, col: 3 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| row: 3, col: 0 | row: 3, col: 1 | row: 3, col: 2 | row: 3, col: 3 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the formatting will no longer work properly if the numbers get higher than 10, because they will then require more space.

---

Regarding your second question on how to calculate the lines necessary to draw a 2D grid:

If you want to draw the lines of a `10*10` tile grid, then you will need to draw 11 horizontal lines and 11 vertical lines. You can generate the coordinates of these lines using the following logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PIXELS_PER_TILE 50
#define SIZE_X 10
#define SIZE_Y 10

int main( void )
{
    int i;

    printf( "Processing lines along X axis:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i <= SIZE_Y; i++ )
    {
        printf(
            "Draw line from [%3d,%3d] to [%3d,%3d]\n",
            0      * PIXELS_PER_TILE, i * PIXELS_PER_TILE,
            SIZE_X * PIXELS_PER_TILE, i * PIXELS_PER_TILE
        );
    }

    printf( "\nProcessing lines along Y axis:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i <= SIZE_X; i++ )
    {
        printf(
            "Draw line from [%3d,%3d] to [%3d,%3d]\n",
            i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, 0      * PIXELS_PER_TILE,
            i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, SIZE_Y * PIXELS_PER_TILE
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the output of that program:

```
Processing lines along X axis:
Draw line from [  0,  0] to [500,  0]
Draw line from [  0, 50] to [500, 50]
Draw line from [  0,100] to [500,100]
Draw line from [  0,150] to [500,150]
Draw line from [  0,200] to [500,200]
Draw line from [  0,250] to [500,250]
Draw line from [  0,300] to [500,300]
Draw line from [  0,350] to [500,350]
Draw line from [  0,400] to [500,400]
Draw line from [  0,450] to [500,450]
Draw line from [  0,500] to [500,500]

Processing lines along Y axis:
Draw line from [  0,  0] to [  0,500]
Draw line from [ 50,  0] to [ 50,500]
Draw line from [100,  0] to [100,500]
Draw line from [150,  0] to [150,500]
Draw line from [200,  0] to [200,500]
Draw line from [250,  0] to [250,500]
Draw line from [300,  0] to [300,500]
Draw line from [350,  0] to [350,500]
Draw line from [400,  0] to [400,500]
Draw line from [450,  0] to [450,500]
Draw line from [500,  0] to [500,500]
```

If you want to draw the lines of a `10*10*10` tile grid (i.e. a 3D grid), then you will need to draw `11*11` lines along the X-axis, `11*11` lines along the Y-axis, and `11*11` lines along the Z-axis (total 363 lines). You can generate the coordinates of these lines using the following logic:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PIXELS_PER_TILE 50
#define SIZE_X 10
#define SIZE_Y 10
#define SIZE_Z 10

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    int j;

    printf( "Processing lines along X axis:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i <= SIZE_Y; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j <= SIZE_Z; j++ )
        {
            printf(
                "Draw line from [%3d,%3d,%3d] to [%3d,%3d,%3d]\n",
                0      * PIXELS_PER_TILE, i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, j * PIXELS_PER_TILE,
                SIZE_X * PIXELS_PER_TILE, i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, j * PIXELS_PER_TILE
            );
        }
    }

    printf( "\nProcessing lines along Y axis:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i <= SIZE_X; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j <= SIZE_Z; j++ )
        {
            printf(
                "Draw line from [%3d,%3d,%3d] to [%3d,%3d,%3d]\n",
                i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, 0      * PIXELS_PER_TILE, j * PIXELS_PER_TILE,
                i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, SIZE_Y * PIXELS_PER_TILE, j * PIXELS_PER_TILE
            );
        }
    }

    printf( "\nProcessing lines along Z axis:\n" );
    for ( i = 0; i <= SIZE_X; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 0; j <= SIZE_Y; j++ )
        {
            printf(
                "Draw line from [%3d,%3d,%3d] to [%3d,%3d,%3d]\n",
                i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, j * PIXELS_PER_TILE, 0      * PIXELS_PER_TILE,
                i * PIXELS_PER_TILE, j * PIXELS_PER_TILE, SIZE_Z * PIXELS_PER_TILE
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I won't post the output of this second program, because it will print several hundred lines of output.

Comment: thank you so much!! real life saver!! i didn't test the code yet but i'll experiment with it right now!! thanks a thousand times man!!

Comment: @Nickname: Note that I just fixed a bug in the second code that I posted (the shorter one). Please don't use my old code.

Comment: thank you again!! word can't describe how thankful i am right now. two days i fought with these stuffs and hesitated so long to state my question here... well thanks everybody specially you Andreas

Comment: @Nickname If you like the answer consider upvoting also